# Какая технология лучше для comet-сервера: tcp sockets, websockets или long polling?

Tags: node.js, comet, flash, php

Делаем игру для контакта. Нужна двухсторонняя связь сервера-клиента для передачи данных. Только от сервера к клиенту из бд(по определенным событиям) и туда-обратно для чата. Никак не могу разобраться, что будет лучше. Планируется высоконагруженное приложение (backend на php, frontend на flash). Больше половины приложения уже написана. Варианты реализовывать comet-сервер на node.js либо на php. В websocket несколько смущает поддержка только в новых версиях браузеров. Полагаю, что tcp sockets будут выигрывать у websockets? В tcp sockets есть поддержка всех браузеров, и меньше данных передается при запросе/ответе(на сколько я знаю). Может быть есть еще какие плюсы или минусы.
Остановились на tcp-sockets.

Comment: фронт же на флеше? Там поддержка вебсокетов 100% есть.

Comment: да, фронт на флеше.

Comment: > Там поддержка вебсокетов 100% есть.
так я и не спорю, вопрос в том, что лучше подойдет

Comment: @s-prosvirnin я бы предпочел вебсокеты. Удобней выходит. Трафик не жрет и само соединение нагрузки особой не дает на сервер.

Comment: а если сравнивать с tcp sockets, не знаете, в чем будет преимущество у websockets? В tcp sockets тоже ведь трафика мало и нагрузки тоже.

Comment: @s-prosvirnin, я по секрету скажу, что и long polling, и websockets строятся поверх обычных сокетов, которые, видимо, и подразумеваются под tcp sockets.

Comment: хм, может и так, но какое это отношение имееет к вопросу?

Comment: @s-prosvirnin, в любом из трех случаев используются стандартные сокеты, вопрос выглядит как "Мне съесть пломбир или все-таки мороженое?". Напрямую к сокету из браузера не получится, можно установить websockify, но все равно это будет websockets-общение. "В tcp sockets есть поддержка всех браузеров" - это способность браузера открывать **http** и **ws** соединения по указанным портам, а не создавать произвольные подключения. И после установления соединения в вебсокетах будет минимальный оверхед, два байта на сообщение, насколько знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/compared/) (Web Application Messaging Protocol).

Answer (score -1):

Только что доделал игру под Вконтакт, держит только 20 активно играющих players. Поэтому tcp сокет не советую. Может, конечно, что то я криворуко сделал(вот код)..
[Сервер на php не держит больше 20 активных игроков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364726/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-20-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Склоняюсь к тому, что придется переделывать на node.js всё.

Comment: Так Вы же со всеми работаете последовательно. Поэтому и медленно. 

При программировании на Си для обслуживания каждого соединения обычно создают (или берут из пула) свой поток (или процесс).

Comment: Мы реализовали через tcp-sockets на nodejs. тестировали нагрузку, по-моему, 10000 активных соединений держит. И, да, у вас последовательная обработка соединений. Для php есть PhpDaemon к примеру, который позволяет асинхронно обрабатывать соединения. Но, я думаю, что для этих целей лучше nodejs.

Comment: согласен, phpDaemon вещь, но лучше node.js. я говорил не про tcp вообще, а про php код. читаю старые надписи смеюсь, немного по другому сейчас думаю.