# Медленная работа алгоритмов

Tags: node.js, tcp, сервер

Друзья, ну это вообще никуда не годится. Несколько циклов по поиску свободного места за столом длятся вечность.

```
var tables = [];
var players = [];
var clients = [];


function check_user_in_db(player_id)
{

    var q1 = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Login = '+player_id;
    e(q1);
    connection.query(q1, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if(rows.length>0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            var q2 = 'INSERT INTO Users(Login) VALUES('+player_id+')';
            e(q2);
            connection.query(q2, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

            });
        }
    });

}

net.createServer(function (socket) {

    socket.setEncoding('utf8');

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        broadcast(data, socket);
    });

    socket.on('end', function ()
    {
    });

    function broadcast(message, sender)
    {
        var player_id = find_player_id_by_sock(sender);
        var result = JSON.parse(message);
        e('Recived method='+result.method + ', param='+result.params[0]);


        switch (result.method) {

            case 'login':

                var newplayer = [];
                newplayer.id = result.params[0];
                clients[num_clients] = sender;
                newplayer.sock_id=num_clients;
                num_clients++;
                players[ newplayer.id ] = newplayer;


                check_user_in_db(newplayer.id);
                update_local_db(newplayer.id);

                var data = { method : 'login_ok', params: "0" };
                send(sender, data );

                break;

            case "create_table":

                var name_table = result.params[0];
                var table_create_id = create_table(name_table);

                join_table(table_create_id, player_id);

                break;

            case "join_table":

                var table_join_id = result.params[0];
                join_table(table_join_id, player_id);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    function delete_player_in_players_array(player_id)
    {
        players.splice(player_id, 1);
    }

    function delete_player_from_table(table_id, player_id)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(tables[table_id].players[i]==player_id){
                tables[table_id].players[i]=-1;
                tables[table_id].free_place+=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function setting_player_in_table(table_id, player_id)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(tables[table_id].players[i]==-1){
                tables[table_id].players[i]=player_id;
                tables[table_id].free_place-=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function join_table(table_id, player_id)
    {
        setting_player_in_table(table_id, player_id);

        var data =[];

        var active_player = tables[table_id].active_player;
        var light = tables[table_id].light;
        var disco = tables[table_id].disco;
        var music = tables[table_id].music;


        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(tables[table_id].players[i]!=-1){

                var id_p = tables[table_id].players[i];
                var info_player = get_user_info(player_id);
                var gold_player = info_player.gold;
                var right_player = info_player.right;

                data.push( {id : id_p, seat : i, gold : gold_player, right : right_player});
                break;
            }
        }

        var msg = []; msg[0] = data;
        send_all(table_id, {method:'update_table', params : msg});

    }

    function find_player_id_by_sock(sender)
    {
        var sock_num = clients.indexOf(sender);
        var player_id = -1;
        players.forEach(function (player) {
                if(player.sock_id==sock_num)player_id = player.id;
            });
        return player_id;
    }

    function find_table_id_by_player_id(player_id)
    {
        var table_id = -1;

        tables.forEach(function (table) {
            for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if(table.players[i]==player_id)
                    table_id=table.id;
            }
        });
        return table_id;
    }

    function find_sock_by_player_id(player_id)
    {
        var num_sock = players[player_id].sock_id;
        var sock = -1;
        sock=clients[num_sock];
        return sock;

    }



    function send_all(table_id, message)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var player_id = tables[table_id].players[i];
            if (player_id != -1) {
                var sock = find_sock_by_player_id(player_id);
                send(sock, message );
            }
        }
    }

    function create_table(table_name)
    {
        var table = [];
        table.players = new Array(12);

        for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            table.players[i]=-1;
        }

        table.active_player = 0;
        table.id = num_tables; num_tables++;

        table.name = table_name;
        table.light = true;
        table.disco = false;
        table.free_place = 12;
        table.music = 'null';

        table.kiss_active = -1;
        table.kiss_passive = -1;

        tables[table.id] = table;

        return table.id;
    }

}).listen(1024);
```

За стол игрок садится только через 1-2 секунды. А цикл в цикле for - это вообще труба, 10 секунд считает. Друзья, подскажите, это node.js так медленно считает результат? Или я что-то не так сделаю? Игру пишу под вконтакт, правильнее сказать, переписываю. Из этой темы:
[Сервер на php не держит больше 20 активных игроков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364726/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-20-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Код Вы привели, это неплохо, но как это все использовать? Вы сделали тестового клиента, что бы это тестить?

Comment: Клиент, только целиковый, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем была ошибка, так и не понял. Но убрал все Сишные конструкции (например, цикл for) и подключил библиотеку underscore. Сейчас игра просто летает. Вот лог:

```
> get_tables :response about 1 ms.
> create_table :response about 1 ms.
> change_table :response about 1 ms.
> get_tables :response about 0 ms.
> create_table :response about 0 ms.
> login :response about 1 ms. get_tables
> :response about 0 ms. create_table
> :response about 0 ms. change_table
> :response about 1 ms. get_tables
> :response about 1 ms. join_table
> :response about 1 ms. change_table
> :response about 1 ms. get_tables
> :response about 1 ms. change_table
> :response about 0 ms. get_tables
> :response about 0 ms. login :response
> about 1 ms. get_tables :response about
> 1 ms. login :response about 0 ms.
> get_tables :response about 0 ms.
> create_table :response about 0 ms.
> change_table :response about 1 ms.
> get_tables :response about 0 ms. login
> :response about 2 ms. get_tables
> :response about 0 ms.
```

Поэтому зря я плохо отзывался о Node.js. Это действительно очень хорошая платформа.

Comment: переписывание на фреймворке/библиотеке может ускорить разработку, но не скорость выполнения. Думаю, что в процессе переписывания, Вы случайно исправили ошибку.

Comment: согласен с вами